# Bower init command error

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, polymer, bower-install

I am trying out Google Polymer. Successfully installed node.js and as you can see below npm and Bower are installed. However, when typing "bower init cmd" it gives me the following error(s): What am I doing wrong and how to best solve this problem? Running Mac OS X (Mav) Thanks in advance.

```
shukhratnegmatov:Polymer shukhratnegmatov$ node -v
v0.10.30
shukhratnegmatov:Polymer shukhratnegmatov$ npm -v
1.4.21
shukhratnegmatov:Polymer shukhratnegmatov$ bower -v
1.3.9
shukhratnegmatov:Polymer shukhratnegmatov$ bower init

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/shukhratnegmatov/.config/configstore'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:647:18)
    at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:70:13)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:40:13)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:26:44)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:26:34)
    at Object.setup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:18:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:72:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
shukhratnegmatov:Polymer shukhratnegmatov$
```

Comment: did you check the permissions on that `.../.config/configstore` dir/file?

Comment: I have similar issue and it looks like my .../.config/configstore folder doesn't exist. I am not sure what I did to cause this...

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, if you have similar situation like me, is that the configstore might be removed by one of your program for some reason.

In this case you can go to open your terminal and type:

open Users/[your username]/.config

[your username] should be your username. I assume it's shukhratnegmatov.

And then you create a folder called configstore!

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue this worked for me just replace 'username'

```
    $ sudo chown username /Users/username/.config/configstore/insight-bower.yml
```